# Is there a limit of devices in a user segment to which FCM can send notifications

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I am relatively new to Firebase, and based on what I've explored I find that there is no limit to the number of devices that can subscribe a token. However, in Notification Console, I can set a user segment as target.
[Firebase Notification Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZqJk.png)

On selecting this, will the notification be received by all the devices for the package or is there a limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the terminology a bit loosely, but if you're asking whether there is a limit on the number of device tokens that can be subscribed to a topic, the answer is: no, there's no limit on that.

There is also no defined limit to the size of the user segment that the Notifications panel in the Firebase console can send messages to.